# Angular - The easiest way to populate $scope

Tags: angularjs

I am currently populating `$scope` arrays like this:

```
$scope.categories = [];

$scope.getCategories = function() {
    ItemService.getCategories().success(function(categories) {
        $scope.categories = categories;
    });
}

$scope.getCategories();
```

Is this really the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Where's the hard part?

Comment: It's not hard, it's just a lot of code

Comment: Why wrap the Service call in a scope function?  No need to, unless your interface is triggering it via some event.  Also, if you want to load categories upon controller initializing you should look at doing it in the route's resolve function or if you're not using route, then in the application's run function.

Comment: No need to wrap the service $http request in function

Comment: @m.e.conroy, as far as I understand the $http.get returns a promise, and I can't handle that and return the result in the service

Comment: The `.success` function of the service is called when the `$http.get` promise is resolved.  No need to wrap it in a scope function, just call the service and set the scope variable in the success function like you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you actually need a getCategories function ? If this is the only place it's called, then you can just remove and leave the service call in directly.

Otherwise your code is as short as it gets for using promises I think, if you're using v1.2. Before 1.2, angular did have automatic promise unwrapping. That is, instead of

```
//$scope.getCategories = function() {
    ItemService.getCategories().success(function(categories) {
        $scope.categories = categories;
    });
//}
```

You could do this instead, which seems much more elegant:

```
//$scope.getCategories = function() {
    $scope.categories = ItemService.getCategories();
//}
```

Issues with this mean it's recently been removed though - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4158 . I think it's possible an alternative will be added in the future if there's a good way to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `resolve` property of your router (assuming you're using a router) to inject the results from `ItemService.getCategories()` into your controller. `resolve` properties block the route from completing until they're fully resolved--it unwraps promises automatically. The code would look something like:

```
angular.module('MyModule').config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/mypage', {
        templateUrl: '/mypage.html',
        controller: 'MyController',
        resolve: {
            categories: function (ItemService) { return ItemService.getCategories(); }
        }
    });
});

angular.module('MyModule').controller('MyController', function (categories, $scope) {
    $scope.categories = categories;
});
```